# AssertionError: expected {} to be a function

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, mocha.js, chai

I'm getting a strange error while using Mocha with Chai for the first time. The only framework I've used before is Jasmine, if that should help you figure out what I'm doing wrong.

I'm simply trying to make sure my constructor doesn't throw an error. I've been able to reduce the code to this, still getting the error:

```
class MyLib {
  constructor() {}
}

export default MyLib;
```

This is the test file:

```
import chai from 'chai';
let { expect } = chai;

import MyLib from '../index';

describe('mylib-js', () => {
  describe('constructor', () => {
    it('should work', () => {
      expect(new MyLib()).to.not.throw();
    })
  });
});
```

This is the output from Mocha:

```
d:\path\to\mylib-js>mocha --require babel-core/register


  mylib-js
    constructor
      1) should work


  0 passing (23ms)
  1 failing

  1) mylib-js constructor should work:
     AssertionError: expected {} to be a function
      at Assertion.an (d:\path\to\mylib-js\node_modules\chai\lib\chai\core\assertions.js:169:10)

      at Assertion.assert (d:\path\to\mylib-js\node_modules\chai\lib\chai\utils\addChainableMethod.js:84:49)
      at Assertion.assertThrows (d:\path\to\mylib-js\node_modules\chai\lib\chai\core\assertions.js:1273:32)
      at Assertion.ctx.(anonymous function) [as throw] (d:\path\to\mylib-js\node_modules\chai\lib\chai\utils\addMethod.js:41:25)
      at Context.<anonymous> (test.js:10:4)
      at callFn (C:\Users\Myuser\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\mocha\lib\runnable.js:315:21)
      at Test.Runnable.run (C:\Users\Myuser\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\mocha\lib\runnable.js:308:7)
      at Runner.runTest (C:\Users\Myuser\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\mocha\lib\runner.js:422:10)
      at C:\Users\Myuser\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\mocha\lib\runner.js:533:12
      at next (C:\Users\Myuser\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\mocha\lib\runner.js:342:14)
      at C:\Users\Myuser\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\mocha\lib\runner.js:352:7
      at next (C:\Users\Myuser\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\mocha\lib\runner.js:284:14)
      at Immediate._onImmediate (C:\Users\Myuser\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\mocha\lib\runner.js:320:5)
```

I have no idea where it gets `{}` from in the error output. What is it trying to tell me?

Comment: What does it say if you have `export default class MyLib { constructor() {} }`?

Comment: @SzabolcsDézsi: When I do that, I get the exact same error

Comment: Should it be `expect(MyLib).to.not.throw();`?

Comment: @dustmouse: "AssertionError: expected [Function: MyLib] to not throw an error but 'TypeError: Cannot call a class as a function' was thrown"

Comment: `new MyLib` is an object not a function. It should be something like `expect( () => new MyLib).not.to.throw()`

Comment: @YuryTarabanko: That makes sense. Add this as an answer and I'll accept!

Comment: @damd  Converted to answer. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As an exception message says `new MyLib` is an object not a function.

It should be something like this to work well with `throw` assertion.

```
expect( () => new MyLib).not.to.throw()
```